# make draggable,droppable div not draggable when other div is dropped inside

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i have a view which shows reservations and tables as div's.
The tables are draggable and droppable the reservations are only draggable.
I want to drag a table to the position you want and than drag a reservation on it.
When the reservation is dropped on it the table needs to be not draggable anymore.
This is my code now:

```
<script>
$(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".draggable",
    snapMode: "outer",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var finalxPos = $(this).css("left").replace("px", "");
        var finalyPos = $(this).css("top").replace("px", "");
        var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
        var posXid = "posX" + itemId;
        var posYid = "posY" + itemId;
        $('input:text[id="' + posXid + '"]').attr("value", finalxPos);
        $('input:text[id="' + posYid + '"]').attr("value", finalyPos);
        },
}).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
    },
    out: function(ev, ui) {
        $(this).draggable({ disabled: false });
    }
});

    $(".draggableres").draggable({
        snap: ".draggable",
        snapMode: "inner"
    });
</script>
```

and my view:

```
<div id="tablewrapper">
   <div class="draggableres reservation">reservation 1</div>

   <div class="draggable table ui-widget-content">
   </div>
</div>
```

As i run it now and i drop a reservation the reservation stops being draggable instead of the table.
it is in a loop so

```
$(".draggable").draggable({disabled: true});
```

is not working because there could be more .draggable divs

Comment: Actually what you have *should* give you exactly what you describe. Note, however, that after you've disabled the draggable container, you'll probably not be able to click-n-drag the contained draggable as the outer (disabled) one will swallow the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you call `.draggable().draggable()` you can disable just the reservation:</s>

**UPDATE**

To disable the table (from being draggable) once a reservation has been dropped, do this:

```
$('.table').droppable({
    activeClass: 'grey',
    hoverClass: 'yellow',
    accept: '.draggables',
    drop: function(event, ui){
       $(this).draggable('disable');
   }
}).draggable();;

$('.draggables').draggable({
    snap: '.table',
    snapMode: 'inner'
});
```

Here is a simple [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/0dcmpjou/)

Comment: if i do this the table reservation is not draggable anymore but the table is. i want the table not draggable when something is dropped on it.

Comment: Just replace `ui.draggable.draggable('disable');` with `$(this).draggable('disable')` I'll update my code.

Comment: :-) let me know if you need any further clarity using your existing code. I simplified my answer to make it easier to adjust.